# Dropbox behind a proxy under ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: 14.04, server, proxy, dropbox

Is it possible to install dropbox under an ubuntu 14.04 server that is behind a proxy with credentials ?

Comment: As it is a server, do you need it to be set via command line, and could you use a alternative (e.g. sftp, ftp, rsync, etc).

Comment: I found this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dropbox#Proxy_settings) on how to setup proxy.

Comment: Thnaks but I already tried and it's not working.  And "Dropbox will only use proxy settings of the form http://your.proxy.here:port"  So I don't think it's possible to add credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide proxy authentication to install Dropbox. Here is a command using which you can do this:

sudo http_proxy="http://username:password@your_proxy:proxy_port" dropbox start -i
or

```
sudo https_proxy="http://username:password@your_proxy:proxy_port" dropbox start -i
```

You have to run the deamon as root, and thus, you have to configure the proxy as root. Setting the http_proxy root env variable on invocation should be enough.